# How do I set a static permanent IP on a raspberry pi

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I have an NOOBs-Raspbian Raspberry Pi. How can I set an permanent static web IP to it?

Comment: I thought it worked differently on a raspberry

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the linked answer @MikhailTal?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it by same way as on another Linux distro. Follow this [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-a-static-ip-address-tutorial/) how make it on main distributions.